Ionic Angular: uppercasing form field value does not work on last character
In order to uppercase the textual input in a form's field, I have following code:
<ion-item>
  <ion-input label="Registration number *" labelPlacement="stacked" formControlName="carRegNr" type="text" autocapitalize="characters" placeholder="Registration number" clearInput="true" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>

Problem now is that the last character of the input does not get capitalized. I.e. when I have a reference to the field value, it is shown as e.g. "CAR-REGi"
<span *ngIf="taskForm.value.carRegNr" class="form-header-label-text">{{taskForm.value.carRegNr}}</span>

Also when sending the value to the back-end, "CAR-REGi" is saved.
Am I overlooking something? How can I make sure the full string is uppercased?

do you need the database saved value to be uppercase?

You should ensure you use (input) instead of onInput, the former is the angular way of event binding, the latter is javascript way.
<ion-item>
  <ion-input label="Registration number *" labelPlacement="stacked" formControlName="carRegNr" type="text" autocapitalize="characters" placeholder="Registration number" clearInput="true" (input)="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>


Also you should use formControlName to store the value of the latest data. Then you can rewrite your code to.
HTML:
<ion-item>
  <ion-input label="Registration number *" labelPlacement="stacked" formControlName="carRegNr" type="text" autocapitalize="characters" placeholder="Registration number" clearInput="true" (input)="onInput()">
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>

<span *ngIf="taskForm.value.carRegNr" class="form-header-label-text">{{taskForm.value.carRegNr | uppercase}}</span>

Now update on the TS to uppercase, if you do not want the uppercase in the database then go for uppercase pipe.
onInput() {
  const ctrl = this.form.get('carRegNr');
  ctrl.patchValue(ctrl.value ? ctrl.value.toUpperCase() : ctrl.value);
}

